# RecordsetClone stopped working between Access 2010 and 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have these two lines:

```
Dim Tst As DAO.Recordset
Set Tst = [Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1].RecordsetClone
```

They work fine in acccess 2010 but for some reason it errors out on access 2016. I'm trying to get a recordset clone of a subform thats on the mainform as a datasheet. I'm assuming it's the call to the subform that's the problem "[Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1] "and Access 2016 dropped support for this syntax or something.  Any insight to get it to work? I've tried a bunch of different references to little avail.

Comment: "stopped working" and "errors out" are not really helpful. What is the full error message?

Comment: And: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: I would try: [Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1].form.RecordsetClone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full syntax for referencing such recordset is:

```
Set Tst = Me![Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1].Form.RecordsetClone
```

where *Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1* is the name of the subform *control*, not the name of the subform.

Comment: This syntax seems like the right track but i get a "Microsoft Office Access can't find the field '|' referred to in your expressions" error when I try it.

Comment: Nevermind. I think i got it. I was being stupid and forgot [Form_Qry_MasterQarl subform1] had the Form call in the front.  I just did what you suggested and Set Tst = Me![Qry_MasterQarl subform1].Form.RecordsetClone   Thanks!

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.